Uniform Convergence of Matrix Series
I have a question about the uniform convergence of matrix series. In Peter D. Lax's Linear Algebra and Its Applications (Page 129), he mentions:

$e^A = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^k}{k!}, e_m(A) = \sum_{k=0}^{m} \frac{A^k}{k!}$
We have already shown that $e_m(A(t))$ tends uniformly to $e^{A(t)}$, and a similar argument shows that $e_m'(A(t))$ converges.

However, I can prove pointwise convergence but am unsure how to establish uniform convergence. Could you please provide guidance on how to prove uniform convergence in this context?
Thank you!

After discussing with @Kakashi, I reached a conclusion. Is this conclusion correct?
Adaptation based on Tao analysis ii Definition 3.5.5 of the Sup Norm, and Theorem 3.5.7 Weierstrass M-Test.
Definition: Let $ f: X \to Y $, where $ X $ is a metric space and $ Y $ is a normed vector space. Define the sup norm of $ f $ by $ \lVert f \rVert_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in X} \lVert f(x) \rVert_Y $.
Theorem: Let $ (f^{(k)})_{k=1}^{\infty} $, where $ f^{(k)}: X \to \mathbb{R}^n $, be a sequence such that the series $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lVert f^{(k)} \rVert_{\infty} $ converges. Then $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f^{(k)} $ converges uniformly to some continuous function $ f $.
Proof: For each component $ f^{(k)}_i $, it is easy to show that $ \lVert f^{(k)}_i \rVert_{\infty} \leq  \lVert f^{(k)} \rVert_{\infty} $. Applying Theorem 3.5.7 Weierstrass M-Test to each component gives the conclusion.

Please quote the relevant portions of the text.

@kobe  I used the estimate (13)′ and was able to demonstrate pointwise convergence, but I am struggling with proving uniform convergence.

The convergence of $e^A = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{A^k}{k!}$ is uniform on compact subsets of $M(n, \mathbb{C})$ since $\|\sum_{k = N}^{\infty}\frac{A^k}{k!}\| \leq \sum_{k = N}^{\infty}\frac{\|A\|^k}{k!}$ and the power series $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$ has infinite radius of covergence.

I have already studied the Weierstrass M-test theorem for functions $f_n: X \to R$ according to Terence Tao's Analysis, $X$ is a metric space here. Now, I am contemplating the Weierstrass M-test theorem for functions $f_n: X \to Matrix_{nn}$. My idea is to first prove that $f_n: X \to Matrix_{nn}$ uniformly converges if and only if each element within the matrix converges uniformly, and then apply the Weierstrass M-test theorem to each individual element. During this process, the inequality $\vert a_{ij} \vert \le \lVert M \rVert_1 \le \sum_{ij} |a_{ij}|$ will be utilized.

Sure, $M$ test works. You don't need to use the individual entries $a_{ij}$. Just using any sub multiplicative matrix norm is enough.

Could you help me write a description and proof of the M theorem for this situation? Does this M theorem hold for any matrix norm?

Or could you help me check the conclusion I updated in the question section? Thank you!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test The M-test works when the functions take values in a Banach space, e.g. $M(n, \mathbb{C})$. The statement and proof is identical to the case where the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$.
